# Email status request panel

Tags: email, status, intuition, panel

I have been tasked to create a panel to display the status of an email server. I want to offer the client the information, status and next steps i.e. 'phone number' in the panel.

How can I display the phone number but encourage the viewer *not* to call and trust the message above?

[image: Example of the proposed email status panel]

Comment: It is not clear to me, whether the email server would be up during the maintenance as well. I am assuming it will and you want to communicate this to the users right? Also what is this more information that you can give over the phone, can you make a quick Q&A section and put a wiki or something and place a link here.. that would help around 80% of the population intending to call.

Comment: Great feedback... please see my revised version for possible solutions to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all about the communication; keep your client informed, make sure that all they need to know is on this page (at any time), and they won't need to phone you. I've drafted a rewrite of the text, giving more emphasis to:

- A title which summarises the content; "client information" isn't very helpful, because the whole page is information for the client.
- What effect the server maintenance will have on the client.
- How the client will know what is going on, when you're actually doing the maintenance.

I've also de-emphasised the phone number, and tried to give it some context about it being a secondary means of communication, after your online updates.

[image: Mockup of server maintenance announcement]